# How to view latest block number of a geth node in the console?

Tags: go-ethereum

How to get information about the state of the blockchain on a geth node?

There are mentions of `admin.chainSyncStatus` [in the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#adminchainsyncstatus), but it is undefined on my 1.4.0 node. The `admin.nodeInfo` shows a hash for the head block, but not the number.

This information is sort-of available in the log, but that is not an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`eth.blockNumber` will give the most recent block your node has processed.

`eth.syncing` gives more information, like what the estimated highest current block is.

```
var sync = web3.eth.syncing; 
console.log(sync);
 /* { startingBlock: 300, currentBlock: 312, highestBlock: 512 } */
```

Comment: Now-a-days, one should `console.log("Syncing is " + await web3.eth.isSyncing());` and `await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `eth.blockNumber` as shown below:

```
> eth.blockNumber
1486570
```

Source: [Ethereum Wiki - JavaScript API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethblocknumber).

Referring to `@Tjaden Hess`'s answer,

1. When `geth` has not started syncing yet:

   ```
   > var sync = web3.eth.syncing; 
   undefined
   > console.log(sync);
   false
   ```
2. After `geth` has started syncing:

   ```
   > var sync = web3.eth.syncing; 
   undefined
   > console.log(sync);
   [object Object]
   undefined
   > sync
   {
     currentBlock: 1486592,
     highestBlock: 1488447,
     startingBlock: 1486592
   }
   ```

Comment: Sometimes `highestBlock` returns: `undefined` maybe 100 times in a loop until it is able to return a valid number, is it normal? Please note that `geth` is syncing. @BokkyPooBah