# How can i calculate curent block number?

Tags: ethash

When i use eth_getWork, i get only 3 parameters:

```
DATA, 32 Bytes - current block header pow-hash
DATA, 32 Bytes - the seed hash used for the DAG.
DATA, 32 Bytes - the boundary condition ("target"), 2^256 / difficulty.
```

How can I calculate curent block number?
I need this for generate dag file and get ca

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view latest block number of a geth node in the console?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/how-to-view-latest-block-number-of-a-geth-node-in-the-console)

Comment: Given the comment on the below answer, perhaps this isn't a duplicate after all...

Comment: @RichardHorrocks You can always undo your close vote by clicking the close button again.

Comment: Good point - retracted :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `eth_blockNumber`

Comment: no, i can`t use this command unsuported in mining. Only eth_getWork and eth_submitWork

Comment: @TarasEndick maybe edit your question and add some more details why you are limited to these calls.

Comment: I'm writing a miner , which connects to the pool. And the pool does not recognize such a command eth_blockNumber. For mining need only eth_getWork and eth_submitWork. I can not understand how I get the number of the block using only these commands .