# web3.eth.syncing returns undefined||false for multiple minutes even syncing is done on the background

Tags: go-ethereum

[How to view latest block number of a geth node in the console:](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3769/4575)
Answer follows:

> ```
> > var sync = web3.eth.syncing; 
> undefined
> > console.log(sync);
> [object Object]
> undefined
> > sync
> {
>   currentBlock: 1486592,
>   highestBlock: 1488447,
>   startingBlock: 1486592
> }
> ```

Please note that I am working on a private blockchain. There are few nodes and network is fragile.

My goal is to get the highestBlockNumber right away no matter what from my local node. But this function `sync = web3.eth.syncing` does return false on many cases and I may need to wait few minutes to get a valid information. And when it does return a valid block number, it has already head of the time.

```
    while [ $startBlockNum == $undefined ]
    do
        startBlockNum=$(echo "$header; mylib.highestBlock()"   | sudo nodejs);
        echo $startBlockNum;
    done

    exports.highestBlock = function() {
       var sync = web3.eth.syncing;
       console.log( sync.highestBlock );
       return sync.highestBlock;
    };
```

For example. When I called: `sync = web3.eth.syncing` highestBlock should be 100 but it returns `false`. I have check sync value inside a loop until it returns a valid information, and when it does it returns 2 minutes more later and returned blockNumber=108 (which highest block# already updated, and actually 8 blocks ahead).

**[Q]** What may be the reason `web3.eth.syncing` returns `undefined` or `false` for multiple minutes even sync is done on the background?

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? If sync = `web3.eth.syncing` returns `undefined` could I trust the value returned by `eth.blockNumber`?

Answer (score 2):

For me with the latest web3 eth.getSyncing was not available.
but **isSyncing** works great. (maybe it has since been renamed ?).

```
const Eth = require('web3-eth');
web3.eth.isSyncing().then(function (r)
{
  console.log("r" + JSON.stringify(r) );
  console.log("currentBlock: " + r['currentBlock']);
  console.log("highestBlock: " + r['highestBlock']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

You should use a callback function:

```
web3.eth.getSyncing(callback(error, result){
if(!err) {
   console.log(result);
   console.log(result.highestBlock);
}
})
```