# Can't connect to RPC on php server

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, php

I am using php to connect RPC server. In localhost, everything works fine. I moved my files to host to test and I realised that $geth->Method_Name() is not working.

If I `print_r($geth`), here is the result.

> GethApi Object ( [_options:protected] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 [host] => 165.227.103.219 [port] => 8545 [assoc] => 1 ) [_address:protected] => http://165.227.103.219:8545 [_id:protected] => 0 )

But if I wanna get block number with `$geth->eth_blockNumber()` here is the result in localhost:

4495121

But in php server:

> ### Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to connect to 165.227.103.219 port 8545: Connection refused' in /home/crypuekb/public_html/GethApi.php:86
>
> | Stack trace:
>     | #0 /home/crypuekb/public_html/GethApi.php(152): GethApi->;__call('eth_blockNumber', Array)
>     | #1 /home/crypuekb/public_html/geth.php(14): GethApi->eth_blockNumber()
>     | #2 /home/crypuekb/public_html/php/db.php(7): require_once('/home/crypuekb/...')
>     | #3 /home/crypuekb/public_html/register.php(4): include('/home/crypuekb/...')
>     | #4 {main}
>     | thrown in /home/crypuekb/public_html/GethApi.php on line 86

Here is the line 86:

`throw new \RuntimeException(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));`

I am using this command to start geth server:

`geth --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal"  --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --light`

As I said, everything works perfect on localhost.. Also my php server and ethereum server is based on different hosts. And I tried my php codes at three different hosts.

Comment: Have you found the issue? I also get the error when testing on localhost

Comment: Did you check that your geth node is in sync? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/how-to-view-latest-block-number-of-a-geth-node-in-the-console